# Error when using Openstreetmaps on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, openstreetmap, fluttermap

How to fix this error?

```
Error : lib/pages/osmmapstest.dart:17:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'layers'.
        layers: [
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-6.0.0/lib/src/map/widget.dart:29:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const FlutterMap({
```

My Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('OpenStreetMaps'),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
          zoom: 13.0,
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate:
                'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Pubspec.yaml
flutter_map: ^6.0.0
latlong2: ^0.9.0
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `flutter_map` version `6.0.0`, you should put a `TileLayer` inside its children like this:

```dart
FlutterMap(
  // ...
  children: [
    TileLayer(
      urlTemplate:
          'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ),
  ],
)
```

So basically, change `layers` to `children` and change `TileLayerOptions` to `TileLayer`.